# CSS3 word-break Firefox and Chrome output differently

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, word-break

I'm attempting to use `word-break` to break a word with long character that exceeds its parent's width.

In this example, I have a `<div>` with `width:43px` and word "play" in it. In chrome, the word fits, but in Firefox, the word got is split over two lines.

[image]

Chrome Screenshot

[image]

Firefox Screenshot

http://jsfiddle.net/chenx/7rYAm/

Here is the jsfiddle, you can try to open it in both Firefox and Chrome to see the difference.
What I want is, they're both output the same result. I'll prefer Chrome as the correct result.

This could affect my apps, as they'll screenshot the view to canvas, and I don't want the customer complaining about output difference between browsers. What's the best practice here? Can `word-break` be standardized across browsers?

Thank you!

Comment: Please post your code and / or a jsFiddle.

Comment: Also, which screenshot is displaying correctly? Do you want Firefox to look like Chrome or vice-versa?

Answer (score 0):

word-break is standardized.  What's not standardized is how wide the word "play" will be.  It depends on the font used, the exact font rasterization algorithm used, on antialiasing settings, and so forth.

On Windows, Firefox and Chrome use two different OS-provided font subsystems (GDI and DirectWrite), which have different rasterization and antialiasing behavior, leading to different widths of text.

The best practice in situations like this is to not use an overly small width for the parent and probably to test what happens when a user with poor eyesight forces a larger font than you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I dislike about browsers doing their own thing.  Firefox uses `word-break: keep-all`.  On the other hand, Chrome uses `word-break: break-word`.